# ggplot histogram: present both overall count in addition to group count in each bin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a histogram using ggplot which on the x axis has speeds and on the y axis has the counts. In addition, each bin shows how many of those were during the day and night. 
I need to present the counts themselves on the plot. I managed to add the counts within each bar but now I would like to present another number, the total count, on top of each bar. Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = speedmh ) , data = GPSdataset1hDFDS48) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=DayActv), bins=15, colour="grey20", lwd=0.2) + ylim(0, 400) +xlim(0,500)+
  stat_bin(bins=15, geom="text", colour="white", size=3.5,
           aes(label=..count.., group=DayActv), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

and this is the result I get:

[image: hist]

How do I add the total count of speeds within each bin to the top of every bar? 
Ideally I would like to make this histogram of proportions of speeds instead of counts, but I think that is too complicated for me at the moment. 
Thank you!!
Mia

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(GPSdataset1hDFDS48)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(GPSdataset1hDFDS48, 20))`.

Comment: As for proportions try something like `label = round(100*..density.., 1)` in `stat_bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add another `stat_bin` command without the grouping:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x = speedmh) , data = GPSdataset1hDFDS48) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=DayActv), bins=15, colour="grey20", lwd=0.2) + ylim(0, 400) + 
  xlim(0,500) +
  stat_bin(bins=15, geom="text", colour="white", size=3.5,
           aes(label=..count.., group=DayActv), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)) +
  stat_bin(bins=15, geom="text", colour="black", size=3.5,
           aes(label=..count..), vjust=-0.5)
```

---

[image]

---

Data:

```
GPSdataset1hDFDS48 <- data.frame(speedmh=rexp(1000, 0.015), DayActv=factor(sample(0:1, 1000,TRUE)))
```